# Excel 2010 not updating links

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a summary .xls workbook that is pulling data from numerous other workbooks.  When the summary sheet is opened, the linked cells only show `#VALUE!`.  If I open all the other workbooks, then the summary workbook works fine.

I am using `SUMIF` formulas, which I believe need to have the corresponding workbooks open to work, but if you use `SUMPRODUCT` you do not need to have them open.

I just tried replacing the wording `SUMIF` with `SUMPRODUCT` but am still getting the same error.

```
=IF(A6="","",
SUMIF('[Stock_count KN.xls]Summary'!$A:$A,A6,'[Stock_count KN.xls]Summary'!$C:$C)
+SUMIF([Stock_count2.xls]Summary!$A:$A,A6,[Stock_count2.xls]Summary!$C:$C)
+SUMIF([Stock_count5.xls]Summary!$A:$A,A6,[Stock_count5.xls]Summary!$C:$C)
+SUMIF([Stock_count4.xls]Summary!$A:$A,A6,[Stock_count4.xls]Summary!$C:$C)
+SUMIF([Stock_count3.xls]Summary!$A:$A,A6,[Stock_count3.xls]Summary!$C:$C)
+SUMIF([Stock_count1.xls]Summary!$A:$A,A6,[Stock_count1.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
```

Comment: You can work your way around `SUMIF` using a combination of `SUM` and `IF` in an array formula. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-sumif-sumifs-function-e65ce689-978e-44b1-a649-160ed5f13b5a) for more information and [here](https://www.sageintelligence.com/tips-and-tricks/2017/06/avoid-value-error-using-sumif-function-workbooks/) for an example for the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided formula with `SUMPRODUCT` would look like this:

`=IF(A6="","",
     SUMPRODUCT(('[Stock_count KN.xls]Summary'!$A:$A=A6)*('[Stock_count KN.xls]Summary'!$C:$C))
    +SUMPRODUCT(([Stock_count2.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6)*([Stock_count2.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
    +SUMPRODUCT(([Stock_count5.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6)*([Stock_count5.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
    +SUMPRODUCT(([Stock_count4.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6)*([Stock_count4.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
    +SUMPRODUCT(([Stock_count3.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6)*([Stock_count3.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
    +SUMPRODUCT(([Stock_count1.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6)*([Stock_count1.xls]Summary!$C:$C)))`

or with `SUM` and `IF` as     **ARRAY FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=IF(A6="","",
SUM(IF('[Stock_count KN.xls]Summary'!$A:$A=A6,'[Stock_count KN.xls]Summary'!$C:$C))
+SUM(IF([Stock_count2.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6,[Stock_count2.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
+SUM(IF([Stock_count5.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6,[Stock_count5.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
+SUM(IF([Stock_count4.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6,[Stock_count4.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
+SUM(IF([Stock_count3.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6,[Stock_count3.xls]Summary!$C:$C))
+SUM(IF([Stock_count1.xls]Summary!$A:$A=A6,[Stock_count1.xls]Summary!$C:$C)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the #VALUE! error once I have made the change you suggested.